# How to get smooth slow motion in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Im trying to get a slow motion on the game im making but it looks realy laggy. Im using the FPS controller from the standard assets given by unity.I attached this script to it :

```
function Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown ("q"))
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0.5;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown ("e")) 
    {
        Time.timeScale = 2.0;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown ("t")) 
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1.0;
    }
}
```

I know this is a similar question to this one http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/39279/how-to-get-smooth-slow-motion.html

but the fixes given on that question won't work.I tried adding a rigidbody to it and putting the Interpolation to Interpolate but it doesn't do anything.(I removed the tick from "Use Gravity" because the character started flying).Im new in unity and scripting so please go easy on me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You should change Time.fixedDeltaTime as well:

```
function Update () {
   if (Input.GetKeyDown ("q")){
      Time.timeScale = 0.5;
      Time.fixedDeltaTime = 0.02F * Time.timeScale;
   }
}
```

To return it to normal motion again you should call these two lines

```
      Time.timeScale = 1;
      Time.fixedDeltaTime = 0.02F * Time.timeScale;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call `SetTimeScale` Method as `target timescale` as argument :)

```
using UnityEngine;
public class TimeScaleSmooth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float targetTimeScale = 1;
    public float speed = 1;

    void Update()
    {
        Time.timeScale = Mathf.MoveTowards(Time.timeScale, targetTimeScale, 
        Time.unscaledDeltaTime * speed);
        //0.02 is default fixedDeltaTime
        Time.fixedDeltaTime = timeScale * 0.02f;
        //FOR TEST
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            SetTimeScale(1);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            SetTimeScale(0.2f);
        }
    }

    public void SetTimeScale(float timeScale)
    {
        targetTimeScale = timeScale;
    }
}
```

- Note that we used `Time.unscaledDeltaTime` which is `independent of timescale`.
- You can tweak `transition time` using `speed`.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually insanely easy. In fact, you don't even have to code anything! Just go into every rigidbody in the scene, and change the interpolation mode to "interpolate" or "extrapolate". They mean very different things, but both have the end result of perfectly smooth slow-motion.